# Using the "foreign" package in R

Tags: r, import, stata

I need to import a STATA data set into R and I have downloaded the "foreign" package. Could you please tell me the steps to "load" the package into R and the steps to import the STATA dataset?

Answer (score 4):

R helplist style answer: RTFM!

Statalist style answer: save your Stata file as usual. In R, type

```
    help(package="foreign")
```

to find out what the commands are. The ones pertaining to Stata would have `.dta` in them, as `.dta` is Stata data file extension. `read.dta(file="path/name.dta")` should work on most occasions. If it does not, try saving your file from Stata as an old version (`saveold filename.dta, replace`).

BTW, it is Stata, not STATA. It's not an acronym, unlike SAS or SPSS... so you don't have to YELL.

P.S. As DWin correctly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290829/874882), you need to load the package:

```
    library(foreign)
```

I assumed that since you seem to know R, remembering that won't be an issue.

Comment: I don't think the R helplist guys are really that mean, are they? I think it would be best if your answer and @DWin's were merged. His answer addresses one part of the question (how to load the package) and your answer addresses another part (how to read a `dta` file). Oh, and wouldn't it be fun if we actually had to write Stata as STaTa?

Answer (score 2):

It rather depends what you  mean by "downloaded". You should not need to download anything, since 'foreign' is included in the standard R installation along with 'base', 'stats', 'utils', 'Matrix', and a few others like 'grDevices'. Whether or not you have already installed the 'foreign' package (unnecessarily) using one of the GUI commands, all you should need to do is:

```
library(foreign) 
?read.dta   # and run the example
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with the same issue therefore the code:

```
library(foreign)
setwd(your working directory)
```

Please note that you have to set the working directory so that R knows where to look for your Stata dta dataset

And last the code:

```
read.dta("name of the dataset .dta")
```

A video for that topic:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCkCz4cu918